# How to work with floating point coordinates for Java's Graphics2D?

Tags: java, graphics2d

So, I've got a fairly typical

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

method, which I'm using to do things like

```
g2.drawOval(200+s.getX().intValue(), 200+s.getY().intValue(), 3, 3);
```

after casting it to a Graphics2D object.

My problem is that I have coordinates expressed in floating point types, in this case, Doubles. What I want is values that are arbitrarily small, that can be scaled to make them actually perceptible. Seeing as how

a) the drawing methods in Graphics2D require ints on input,

b) the scaling is an independent step and

c) my original values need to be int-ified without regards to scaling, I have some concerns whether this will display stuff properly.

Indeed, if I set the raw coordinates to a tiny values, then apply scaling to compensate, the result is predictable: the coordinates are treated as zero, because that's what they approximate to when being int-ified.

Is there some way to get around this so that I have both floating point coordinates and scaling which works?

Answer (score 2):

How about using java.awt.geom package for 2D objects that provide double precision? e.g.

```
Ellipse2D.Double ellipse  = 
new Ellipse2D.Double(200+s.getX(), 200+s.getY(), width, height);
```

check the package summary http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/package-summary.html